# How far would a ship travel during 123 days at warp 9.5?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, warp

If a ship travels at warp 9.5 (TNG-era warp scale) and encounters no resistance or gravitational affects that change its velocity, and assuming infinite fuel is available, how far does it travel in 123 days?

Frame of reference:

In the episode "Remember Me" of TNG's 4th season, Dr Crusher is stuck inside an experimental warp bubble by Wesley.

After the rest of the crew disappears she decides to try to get to Tau Alpha C from where she is, and asks the computer how long it would take at warp 9.5 to reach there. The computer responds that it would take 123 days. [Synopsis](http://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/episodes/tng4.htm#rememberme).

Comment: 123 days seems like an odd time frame. Is there a reason it isn't 100 days or something else that feels more standard?

Comment: Ill add it to the question, thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: I assumed it was because 123 days is almost exactly one-third of a year.

Comment: It would travel the distance between the Enterprise and Tau Alpha C.

Comment: Not an answer, but the real-world star [Aldebaran](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aldebaran) is referred to as "Alpha Tauri," and is a multiple star system with a third star called "Alpha Tauri C."  It is, however, only 65 light years away, so it's clearly not as far away as the fictional Tau Alpha C.

Comment: @Nerrolken Tau is a Greek letter and almost certainly does not refer to the constellation Taurus, from which Aldebaran gain is designation of Alpha Tauri ("brightest star in Taurus").

Comment: @Nerrolken It is only 65 light years away *from Earth*, but since the Enterprise wasn't at Earth, that's completely irrelevant. Also, Tau isn't Tauri, as ADF points out.

Comment: "If there's nothing wrong with me, maybe there's something wrong with the universe." -- Dr. Beverly Crusher, greatest line ever uttered on television (or, possibly, anywhere)

Comment: @DavidConrad I know Tau isn't Tauri, that's why I didn't add it as an answer. The point I was making was that we have no real-world analogs or parallels to which we can anchor the fictional and famously inconsistent warp-speed distance math. But Aldebaran being 65 light years from Earth *is* relevant in ruling it out as an analog for Tau Alpha, because something that takes 4 months at almost maximum warp from a Federation outpost isn't going to be anywhere near Federation space anymore, let alone Earth, which is near the heart of the Federation.

Comment: The Enterprise and other starships travel at the speed of plot.

Comment: @Mark I want to use your comment as the answer haha

Comment: also @Mark [tos plot lol link](https://startreklives.files.wordpress.com/2008/09/2-quadrants.jpg) That shows just how far the original 1701 Ent traveled in two of its missions.... quite possibly in two episodes.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

That's actually a surprisingly hard question to answer. Assuming we use the standard logarithmic scale offered in the [TNG Technical Manual](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation_Technical_Manual), then you're looking at Warp 9.5 being approximately 1800-2000 times the speed of light. In 123 days, assuming no malfunction and unlimited fuel, you could therefore travel 606 light years:

[image]

This tallies quite nicely with the Warp Speed calculations in the (unpublished) [Voyager Technical Manual](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Voyager_Technical_Manual) which refers to Warp 9.**6** as being around 1900 times the speed of light

[image]

Unfortunately, nothing in life is that easy. The TNG Manual stresses that your speed is **highly variable** due to the interstellar medium you're traveling through, not just resistance and gravitation but also changes in subspace.

> The actual values are dependent upon interstellar conditions, e.g.,
>   gas density, electric and magnetic fields within the different regions
>   of the Milky Way galaxy, and fluctuations in the subspace domain.
>   Starships routinely travel at multiples of c, but they suffer from
>   energy penalties resulting from quantum drag forces and motive power
>   oscillation inefficiencies.

---

With regard to the episode TNG : Remember Me, it's important to note that when Dr. Crusher asks the computer how far Tau Alpha C is from her present location, she's in a pocket dimension created **by her own mind**. There's no specific confirmation that this figure is in any way accurate.

Comment: Nice response. However, voyager was knocked 70,000 ly away, if that calculation is correct it should only take them a year to get home? [link](http://star-trek.answers.wikia.com/wiki/If_Voyager_had_never_found_any_shortcuts_back_to_the_Alpha_Quadrant,_would_it_realistically_have_only_taken_75_years_to_get_back_home)

Further that goes on to state it would take them 5.56 years to get home. Yet in cannon in the actual series it says decades.... This is why warp speed confuses me hah

Comment: @MrDobilina - I was thinking exactly the same. The whole Voyager series would be done in one season.

Comment: You know, Richard, you've got so many badges they don't fit clearly next to Buffy, above.

Comment: @MrDobilina - Discussed at length [here](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Intrepid_class#Warp_drive_capabilities). Basically they retconned in later episodes to say that they can only sustain high warp for approx 12 hours due to the need for fuel. Also, Voyager was not fully fitted out yet.

Comment: @Richard lovely. I do love when someone knows what they are talking about! Sorry if it seemed a noobish question!

Comment: @Wikis however it would explain why TOS enterprise could get from UFP space to the edge of the galaxy in one episode ;)

Comment: @MrDobilina - Warp speed in Star Trek is highly inconsistent. MST3K mantra in full operation - It's just a show. Relax.

Comment: @MrDobilina - Although Voyager was knocked 70,000 ly away on a straight line path, I think the calculated time was based on assuming a curved path that avoided getting too close to the center of the galaxy, since [this page](http://www.cygnus-x1.net/links/lcars/blueprints/Voyager-Technical-Manual/Page_17.jpg) of the Voyager tech manual says "The 75 year figure mentioned elsewhere assumed that the ship could maintain Warp 9.6 for that period of time", and the chart Richard posted from the same tech manual said warp 9.6 was 1909 light speed, and 75 y * 1909 l.y./y = 143,000 l.y.

Comment: @Hypnosifl - Also, they were spouting complete crap in the early episodes. That doesn't help.

Comment: @MrDobilina considering our solar system sits in one of the outer arms of the galaxy, and kirk enterprise is a deep space mission already pointed towards the outer edge of the galaxy, it's completely logical.

Comment: From the answer and the comments, I am tempted to answer that the ship would a plot-guided-distance in a plot-guide-time :-p

Comment: @SJuan76 - It's certainly a real coincidence that they found their way home in the very last episode, rather than the week afterwards.

Comment: @Hypnosifl The curved path part is true (one of the earliest Hirogen episodes showed part of it, I think), but it wouldn't have bumped the time up so much.  I'd estimate the maximum increase due to a curved path being ~1.57 times as long, using half the circumference of a circle, and what was onscreen was more direct than that

Comment: @Izkata - If we want to come up with an in-universe reason, maybe in addition to the path being curved at a large scale, we could imagine it was also wiggly to steer clear of local areas that are less favorable (for whatever Treknobabble reason) to warp travel.

Comment: @Hypnosifl - Also, Janeway stops every week to pick up a camera crew and have an adventure.

Comment: @Richard - Yes, but the tech manual does say that the 75 year figure is based on the idealization of a constant speed of warp 9.6, "which we know will not be possible". I would have expected the stuff in the tech manual to have a little more logic and internal consistency than any random bit of technobabble on the show, since the manual was written by Okuda and Sternbach at the beginning of the show as a guide for the writers (not sure if it was written before or after the first few episodes though, maybe some other writer came up with 75 years and they were stuck with it).

Comment: @Hypnosifl - There are some startling inconsistencies across the entire Trek estate. I've always felt that the fun is in trying to tie the whole thing together *despite* these problems, like trying to fit five different jigsaws together to make a single coherent picture

Comment: @Hypnosifl so more plot convenience then?